# Php cURL is not working on aliexpress

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch the products list from aliexpress but it is not working its redirecting me to the homepage the url from which I am fetching the product is list is following

```
url="https://m.aliexpress.com/search.htm?keywords=mobile";
```

this is my curl code which is not working properly.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://m.aliexpress.com/search.htm?keywords=mobile/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    ':authority:www.aliexpress.com',
    ':method:GET',
//  ':path:/item/2017-New-Summer-Fashion-Mens-T-Shirts-Slim-Fit-Short-Sleeve-T-Shirt-032/32798976881.html',
    ':scheme:https',
    'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
//  'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'cache-control:no-cache',
    'cookie:ali_apache_id=10.181.15.98.1496226301876.152542.8; ali_beacon_id=10.181.15.98.1496226301876.152542.8; aep_common_f=aEhfbgrZ7e4e9UmjuOWm1CANyaLLaqTDc80Oan6/v5duIrtz3XfvQQ==; cna=BIi1EWdCs1QCAS43pj2EYRUu; _uab_collina=149806153775875750712574; _mle_tmp0=eNrz4A12DQ729PeL9%2FV3cfUx8KvOTLFScnF1dDR1dDV2dLU0sDSxNLEwsTR0cjN2dHI0MTM0NzNW0kkusTI0sbQwMTczMjExtDDSSUxGE8itsDKojQIApLsX8Q%3D%3D; aep_history=keywords%5E%0Akeywords%09%0A%0Aproduct_selloffer%5E%0Aproduct_selloffer%0932788134848%0932798976881; xman_us_t=x_lid=bg1134819498lzch&sign=y&x_user=bUBd5Jk0irdh4KaPNADUTaZgZPbhimHjaVryhYI9YCI=&ctoken=18y_131g18r61&need_popup=y&l_source=aliexpress; xman_us_f=zero_order=n&x_locale=en_US&x_l=0&last_popup_time=1496226312427&x_user=BG|Nikola|Mihaylov|ifm|754321409&no_popup_today=n; intl_locale=en_US; aep_usuc_f=isfm=y&site=glo&c_tp=USD&x_alimid=754321409&isb=y&region=BG&b_locale=en_US; intl_common_forever=iP9SzYB6uR11n9PDuziWZV+m6wS5lewBhe0mchSYZzPnAbhr0LZabw==; _ga=GA1.2.1468541176.1496226329; _gid=GA1.2.15678206.1498472399; JSESSIONID=C8CB956B69CC08A9B351C25C869BBF29; _umdata=70724C19E34629158F306CE35FF4594FD67FF1CAB2345D48D8DBB0AA935079C88BF9397A2C0FD39DCD43AD3E795C914C85C011A26645999BFC392F47E8EAF27C; ali_apache_track=mt=1|ms=|mid=bg1134819498lzch; ali_apache_tracktmp=W_signed=Y; acs_usuc_t=acs_rt=4426ebd3d8e64e528a12a78ded645f48&x_csrf=o8z03s_owisa; xman_f=A2GX/Y1rs0cttixwSxevdzKgU2yRTOLeKBX7fdKnMDdXVLpqHphq8YkU+FAR6NBhi7hO5A7zc3/N6J/t/H9GWyHI+NwKJhVmLd4RElBNdA8pz3lnGKz0ftxea14UUDnFXkIy11hLAIx4XZqeotvVY5xqQ2mHDWxJdTYyFGUJp2NUu5sA+A+/LFaZo/EhWIfeloGoaQnpsd2ps2jdCJ6JyDiKEeiASt17bEr5yszxaPRfbd7hfZUA4PIxgI7v5xSjj851b0fxepl6UbWi17mb+nk2O1VDuqt3mITEb3d0ZfzzZpWy9G6CuVbj/20I8NLAlFY52SkZtltbyMAImZfaIaEFhz350zco; xman_t=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; __utmt=1; __utma=3375712.1468541176.1496226329.1498476312.1498478200.3; __utmb=3375712.5.10.1498478200; __utmc=3375712; __utmz=3375712.1498476312.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); isg=AgcHaslcEs7cDpY8UNqaqtarlrsRpIzPoZDqYtndZhbiSDMK4NzOPvZIzj7t',
    'pragma:no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests:1',
    'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response == false){
    echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($ch) . "(" . curl_errno($ch) . ")";
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
$dom  = str_get_html($response);


echo $dom;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer, but comments too big to put in the comments field

first off, your HTTPHEADER's make no sense, but that's not your problem. the problem is that the products are NOT in the html at all, but fetched by javascript, from https://m.aliexpress.com/search/mainsearch/asy/GetMainSearchDataJson.do

, but in order to fetch products from there, you first need a valid session cookie, and token called `pageId` (no, its not something sensible like a number, its a hash of some kind, best guess, its probably a hex-encoded SHA1 hash, for whatever reason), else you get an access denied error. problem is, this pageId token is generated with javascript in the browser. in order to calculate the pageId in PHP, you'll need to reverse-engineer the javascript calculating the pageId, and implement that algorithm in PHP. i think the code to generate the pageId hash starts in https://i.alicdn.com/aefe-mobile-global/standalone/??venus.e2980efc.js , but i can't be arsed digging further for you (unless you're willing to pay for it, ofc), good luck